# Approval Request 2FA authentication

Tags: two-factor-authentication

With Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator I generate a Time-based One Time Password (TOTP).

User need to insert the code in my website complete two factor authentication.

How to generate a push notification "Approval Request" in Authenticator App with a custom account?

Like described here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7026266?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Microsoft-Authenticator-iOS-now-supports-push-approval-for/ba-p/245120

Could not find any technical documentation

Comment: I use the same flow for LastPass. Unfortunately I think it requires that your website would need it's own companion verification app to handle the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't build that sort of integration with Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator.

One *option* you have is to check out the [Authy push notification API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/push-authentications). It uses the [Authy app](https://authy.com/) which is free to download for your users, and can perform authentication via push notification or drop back to in app code or even SMS.

Let me know if that helps at all.